# How to add a credit payment to QuickBooks using C#

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am able to transfer bills to QuickBooks using C#.NET (and QBFC), but I would like to send credit bills. For example, I would like to be able to make an advance payment. On Screen, I have to change the type to credit (not bill).

How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this. If anyone know any other solutions, please update. I used IVendorCreditAdd & IMsgSetRequest.AppendVendorCreditAddRq() to create credit payment